# "1дней", "2дней" вместо "1 день", "2 дня"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице голосов пользователя https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/%id_user%/%username%?tab=votes, то, как сейчас отображаются временные интервалы "1дней", "2дней", предлагаю заменить на "1 день", "2 дня" и т.п. с учетом количества дней.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновлено:**

Так же нужны пробелы между цифрами для секунд и минут, возможно еще для часов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Поправил. Строки будут доступны после ближайшего развертывания сборки.